# s.erase is not working when trying to remove spaces from a string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to remove the spaces from a string to validate a Palindrome phrase. I have looked up other methods, but my professor literally copy and pasted the remove space for loop in our instructions but I can't get it to work and he says he doesn't want us going to the internet for help. I am trying to remove spaces from a phrase like "too hot to hoot" to validate it. I can get my program to work with single words like "bob", but not phrases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char input[100];
cout << "Please enter a word/phrase: ";
cin >> input;

for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++)
{

    while (s[i] == ' ')//getting "s" is undefined error
        s.erase(i,1);
}

int i = 0; 
int j = strlen(input)-1;
bool a = true;

    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != input[j])
        {
            a = false;
        }
        j--;
    }

    if(a)
    {
        cout << input << " is a Valid Palindrome." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<< input << " is not a Valid Palindrome." << endl;
    }

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suspect that by asking you not to go to the Internet for help, your professor is trying to motivate you to **use a debugger** to diagnose the problem yourself. Have you tried this? What do you see when you single-step the code that isn't working properly?

Comment: The funny thing about the debugger is that he says we will get to it later. He has very lightly gone over it, but not really enough to understand much.

Comment: Hint: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/16455/

Comment: Since the error says *s is undefined*, you do understand what that means? And you do understand what the erasing loop is doing? Now think about the error. s definitely is undefined. It’s nowhere in your program. From what are you trying to erase spaces? Now you should understand how to fix this. Look at the code where you took that part and understand what it does and how and why first, then use it.

Comment: You probably want to 1) replace char input[100] with a std::string. 2) replace s with input

Comment: I saw my issue with using s instead of input, so I got that fixed. My only issue with using the std::string is that he hasn't taught us this method, so I know that if I use it on the assignment he will know I went outside of the book (that he wrote) to find a solution.

Comment: Thats good if you do that. char* is reserved for experts!!!!! Who are optimizing every bit of their memory! Dont do that. Let him know this is bad. Even I am in college. They are teaching us C. And its horrible. Like they give us programs to define functions and cut everything from main and put in that function and call that function from main and exit. Its ridiculus!!!! @Squanching

Comment: Yeah my professor is big on trick questions. I'm already confused as it is so when he throws in the trick questions, that he acknowledges are trick questions, I just go blank. I'm have a wonderful time :|

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not copy the result from temporary variable 's'. So, the modified codes should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char input[100];
    cout << "Please enter a word/phrase: ";
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);

    string s(input);    // define a temporary variable 's'
    int i = 0; 
    while (i < s.length())
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\n')
        {
            s.erase(i, 1);      // erase from variable 's', other then 'input'
            continue;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // copy result from 's' to 'input'
    sprintf(input, "%s", s.c_str());

    int j = strlen(input) - 1;
    bool a = true;

    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] != input[j])
        {
            a = false;
        }
        j--;
    }

    if (a)
    {
        cout << input << " is a Valid Palindrome." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << input << " is not a Valid Palindrome." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```